# Resources for entanglement entropy in condensed matter systems and black hole thermodynamics

Tags: black-holes, condensed-matter, entropy, resource-recommendations, ads-cft

Over the last month or so, I have set it upon myself to teach myself the AdS/CFT correspondence. In particular, I am interested in the connection between black hole entropy and entanglement entropy in condensed matter systems. However, I really need to learn more about the more finer details of entanglement entropy and black hole thermodynamics before I dive into AdS/CFT. Therefore, any resources on these two subjects would be greatly appreciated.

To be precise, I am looking at books/articles/websites (preferably some open-access pdf) which assumes an understanding of Sakurai-level quantum mechanics, some quantum field theory and special relativity. I am also familiar with condensed matter field theory and second quantization, so it's okay if it assumes some former knowledge in these topics. I would prefer pedagogical texts, as comprehensive as possible and with a lot of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of review articles and books on these topics. But most of them require some knowledge of basic General Relativity and QFT.  For Black hole thermodynamics I found the reviews by [Jacobson](http://www.physics.umd.edu/grt/taj/776b/lectures.pdf) $[1]$ and [Ross](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0502195/) $[2]$ very useful.

On EE from condensed matter (QFT) point of view there are papers by Cardy and others. But for those you need CFT background. Here is a "non-technical" [article](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0505193) $[3]$. You can look at the references therein, if you are interested.

For entanglement entropy of black holes probably the best article is [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.3712) $[4]$. You can find most of the useful references, which you are looking for, there.

I could give you more references but not sure they will be useful at all.

---

$[1]$ T. Jacobson, "Introductory Lectures on Black Hole Thermodynamics".
$[2]$ S. F. Ross, "Black hole thermodynamics", arXiv:hep-th/0502195.
$[3]$ P. Calabrese and J. Cardy, "Entanglement entropy and quantum field theory: a non-technical introduction", *Int. J. Quant. Inf.* **4** (2006) 429.
$[4]$ S. N. Solodukhin, "Entanglement entropy of black holes", *Living Rev. Relativity* **14**, (2011), 8.

Comment: Please give me any references you have on the subject--I'm sure they will be useful. Thanks for the references you've already included.